# Please create the file and run this command again

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a problem when I want to build an APK I have these errors but when I build a debug I'm fine and there are no problems the error is displayed only when the flutter build apk command how to build an APK correctly please tell me I'm new to all this. Thank you for earlier for your response.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.

> Keystore file not set for signing config config

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Have you seen: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app/build.gradle, change the buildTypes to something like this.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

}
```

Or if you have the `key.jks` file, then mention the path of the key.jks file in `key.properties` file.